# Python: How to deploy object detection model using flask api

Tags: python, flask, data-science, object-detection

I have used Tensorflow-GPU for object detection on my laptop.
Now the management team wants to check it with URL at its own place.
I never published/deployed the model on the web as I am not python developer but now I have to do that.For that I tried to go through some online tutorials for Flask but they weren't that helpful.

How can I publish the model using Flask API?
Are there any guidance/blog/video to deploy the Object detection model on URL using Flask?

my project structure is something like this

[image]

Comment: When I was getting started with model deployment using flask I referred to DeepLizard's tutorials : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xrwRnXk_yCPtnqqo4_u2YGL

Comment: If this seems relevant, I had wrote a code to expose the model through REST api, [Here](https://github.com/saurabh-slacklife/ml-data-model-microservice)
--
The idea is to load the model/pickle into memory and whenever you get an API call, you just call the serialized version of your model.
--
file - hotel_recommendations and method- post
Line returns the prediction- prediction_crystall_ball().crystall_ball_prediction(input_query)

Comment: Thanks, @Yatin please check the attached screenshot of my project structure. mostly all my project structure same but don't know how to handle it with js/HTML/python flask API for publishing

Comment: thanks @Saurabh please check my above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a flask restful api which can be used with any other services.

1. For image-based tasks, it's always smart to use `base64` encoded images while making a request. That cuts a good amount of bandwidth overhead.
2. Here, I use my dummy template while prototyping very simple ML/DL models to just test with rest API.

It has a simple `test` route which tests if the server is live or not, finally, another route to handle post requests with base64 images, it converts the base64 image to `numpy` array (convenient for passing to ML models).

You can change the intermediate parts to make it work for you.

***ml_app.py***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import werkzeug, os
import json
import numpy as np
import base64


class NumpyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder): # useful for sending numpy arrays
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files')
parser.add_argument('imgb64')
# add other arguments if needed

# test response, check if live
class Test(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'status': 'ok'}


class PredictB64(Resource): # for detecting from base64 images


    def post(self):
        data = parser.parse_args()
        if data['imgb64'] == "":
            return {
                    'data':'',
                    'message':'No file found',
                    'status':'error'
                    }

        img = data['imgb64']
        #print(img)


        br = base64.b64decode(img)
        im = np.frombuffer(br, dtype=np.uint8). reshape(-1, 416, 3) # width will be always 416, which is generally the bigger dimension
        # reshape with the actual dimension of your image
        #print(im.shape)


        #print(type(im))
        #print(im.shape)


        if img:
            r = # call your model here
            #print(r)

            return json.dumps({
                    'data': json.dumps(list(r)), #(images), # may change based on your output, could be a string too
                    'message':'darknet processed',
                    'status':'success'
                    }, cls=NumpyEncoder)
        return {
                'data':'',
                'message':'Something when wrong',
                'status':'error'
                }



api.add_resource(Test, '/test')
api.add_resource(PredictB64,'/predict_b64')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000, threaded=True)
```

To run, simply do:

`python ml_app.py`

more examples: https://github.com/zabir-nabil/flask_restful

darkent/yolo: https://github.com/zabir-nabil/tf-model-server4-yolov3

Comment: please check the attached screenshot of my project structure. mostly all my project structure  same but don't know how to handle it with js/HTML/python flask API for publishing

Answer (score 0):

I always use GCP to deploy my API's.

Follow the Official documentation to host your API on Google Cloud Run

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).